# Is there a Non-perturbative renormalization algorithm?

Tags: renormalization, regularization, non-perturbative

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there non-perturbative RENORMALIZATION ?? if so how it works?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34147/is-there-non-perturbative-renormalization-if-so-how-it-works)

Is there a non-perturbative renormalization algorithm ???, for example to avoid the divergent integrals and so on :) , for example given a theory with action $ S $ can we apply some numerical or other methods to get finite corrections and finite results ??